# Git pull from another machine using IP Address and path

Tags: git, windows-10

How do I pull the source code from Machine B into machine A (both running Windows 10)?

- Machine A: IP 192.168.0.10 , Git repo is at `c:\work\mysrc\mysrc.git`
- Machine B: IP 192.168.0.11 , Git repo is at `e:\src\mysrc.git`

Things I have tried on machine A:

```
git remote add machineB git://192.168.0.11/e/src/mysrc.git
git pull machineB master
fatal: unable to connect to 192.168.0.11:
192.168.0.11[0: 192.168.0.11]: errno=No error
```

Things I have tried on machine B:

```
cd e:\src\.git
touch git-daemon-export-ok
git daemon --base-path=. --enable=receive-pack --reuseaddr --informative-errors --verbose
```

References: [this page](http://railsware.com/blog/2013/09/19/taming-the-git-daemon-to-quickly-share-git-repository/)

Comment: Did you try pinging 192.168.0.11? The connectivity seems to be the problem.

Comment: Are both machines on the same network? The IP addresses you have are for private networks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing : they are both accessible - I can ping .